# How to create a Rest Query for Yahoo Weather

Tags: python, rest, python-3.4, yql, yahoo-weather-api

I'm coding in Python 3.4 and trying to create a Rest Query to access Yahoo Weather Data.
   I've created a Client ID and Secret for Yahoo's YQL, but I'm not sure how to proceed.
   Thanks in advance for your help.
   My Code looks as follows:

```
import requests
import yql
import json

def get_forecast(zipcode):
    clientID = "xyz"
    clientSecret = "abc"
    req_str = "select * from rss where url='http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss/{0}_f.xml'".format(zipcode)

    ...???
```

Comment: if it helps, have a look at [my utility](https://github.com/pynchia/flickrfav) to download my fav pics from flickr

Comment: You are asking a wrong question. Your question should be: how to make a POST request in python. Forget about Yahoo weather, learn about HTTP requests and their implementation in python first. Without any background on Yahoo weather it looks you would need a POST with data here.